# $\left<2\right>\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/\left<2\right>=\{0\otimes\overline{0}, 2\otimes\overline{1}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I found that $\left<2\right>\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/\left<2\right>=\{0\otimes\overline{0}, 2\otimes\overline{1}\}$ but I failed to check why $0\otimes\overline{0}\neq2\otimes\overline{1}$. It seems like nothing happes even if they are equal. Could any one give me help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let consider the module isomorphism
\begin{align}
&\mu:\Bbb Z\to 2\Bbb Z&
&x\mapsto 2x
\end{align}
Then we have module isomorphisms
$$\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\xrightarrow\sim\Bbb Z\otimes(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\xrightarrow[\mu\otimes 1]\sim 2\Bbb Z\otimes(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$$
which maps $\bar 1\mapsto 2\otimes\bar 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the bilinear map $\varphi: \langle 2\rangle \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z / \langle 2\rangle \to \mathbb Z / \langle 2\rangle$ given by $(2a, b) \mapsto ab$. Since $\varphi(2, 1) = 1 \ne 0$, it follows that $\langle 2\rangle \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z$ itself cannot be trivial.

Comment: +1 This also implies that $2 \otimes \overline{1}$ is nontrivial, as requested.